# At what points is the function discontinuous

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am stuck on this math problem in my precalc class. If you have time, could you please explain how to do this to me? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, a function is discontinuous at points where you have to lift your pencil from the page when you draw it's graph. Of course, it's also not continuous where it isn't even defined (like at a vertical asymptote). Try applying that to your function!

Comment: This answer is correct, but I would like to point out that disturbingly, shockingly, many texts would call $-1$ a point of discontinuity here.

Comment: So the points at which it is discontinuous would be 2 and -1?

Comment: I don't really see a problem with that, and in my response I tried to guide Alan to include -1 in his answer. This is precalc, not rigorous analysis.

Comment: Sweet, I guess I was over thinking it then :P That seems fairly simple. Thank you guys!

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree with @ZachEffman’s second comment. If you define a function to be discontinuous where it isn’t defined, then $\sqrt x$ will have to discontinuous for all negative numbers. More fully, for a function to be discontinuous at $a$, it must be defined at $a$ and not continuous there. And continuity will not even be considered at points of nondefinition.

Comment: That's certainly true, but at the precalculus level pretty much everybody treats vertical asymptotes as points of discontinuity. I agree with you on what the true definition of discontinuous should be.